# How can I handle different template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, string, templates, hashtable

I need to impelement HashTable class in C++, so I decided to create a template class:

```
template <typename key_t, typename value_t>
class HashTable {};
```

And in this case, i need to hash different types of keys.
I tried something like that:

```
if(typeid(std::string) == typeid(_key)) {
    return StrSum(_key) % TABLE_SIZE;
} else {
    return _key % TABLE_SIZE; 
}
```

But in case that typeid() isn't compilation time defined function, my compiler (MSVS) hitting me an error that "...there is no defined operator % for std::string".

So, my question is: How can I do this?

Comment: Do what the standard [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) does provide a hash function as a defaulted template parameter. As a container implementer you should not be pushing decisions that can be made at compile time to run time. Especially `typeid` stuff which is notoriously slow.

Comment: damn too late with an answer, to back up my comment. You may as well see the code anyway [here](http://ideone.com/KmkxFR). The hash_table implementation is only a vehicle for demonstration and is obviously not intended for proper use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloading:

```
void hash_impl(const std::string& x)
{
    return StrSum(x) % TABLE_SIZE;
}

template <typename T>
void hash_impl(const T& x)
{
    return x % TABLE_SIZE; 
}
```

Your `if`...`else` can be replaced with a call to `hash_impl(_key)`.

---

Alternatively, you can use `if constexpr(...)` in C++17:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(_key)>, std::string>{}) 
{
    return StrSum(_key) % TABLE_SIZE;
} 
else 
{
    return _key % TABLE_SIZE; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but now I have new question to you: how I should call hash_impl if I have not string key. I mean, is calling like that:  hash_impl(incomingKey) or hash_impl<key_t>(incomingKey) ?

Comment: `hash_impl(incomingKey)` will be fine, as the template argument will be deduced *(and the non-template function will have priority over the template one)*.